# Settings must be of the form "name=value". at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount when running Azure webjob timer trigger

Tags: azure-webjobssdk, azure-storage-account, formatexception, timer-trigger

getting the below error when running in one particular Azure env. I tested in two other envs also its working fine there.
Checked the azure storage connection string for that env ,it seems to be in correct format.

Can Someone please help!

Unhandled exception.

```cs
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException: The listener for function 'SchedulerFunctions.RunEpTask' was unable to start. 
---> System.FormatException: 
Settings must be of the form "name=value". at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.<>c.
<Parse>b__97_0(String err) at 
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseStringIntoSettings(String connectionString, Action`1 error) at 
Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.ParseImpl(String connectionString, CloudStorageAccount& accountInformation, Action`1 error) at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount.Parse(String connectionString) at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_TimerStatusDirectory() in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 77 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusBlobReference(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 144 at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.GetStatusAsync(String timerName) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Scheduling\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:line 93 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:line 99 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:line 70 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 68 --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.RecoverableException.TryRecover(ILogger logger) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Exceptions\RecoverableException.cs:line 81 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean allowRetry) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 79 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:line 61 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.CompositeListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\CompositeListener.cs:line 39 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ListenerFactoryListener.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ListenerFactoryListener.cs:line 47 at 
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.ShutdownListener.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\ShutdownListener.cs:line 29 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.StartAsyncCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\JobHost.cs:line 101 at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token) at Deloitte.Audit.Workflow.NotificationService.Program.Main() in F:\Vsts\agent-15\_work\48\s\WebApi\src\Deloitte.Audit.Workflow.NotificationService\Program.cs:line 21 at Deloitte.Audit.Workflow.NotificationService.Program.<Main>()
```

getting the below error when running in one particular Azure env. I tested in two other envs also its working fine there.
Checked the azure storage connection string for that env ,it seems to be in correct format.

Can Someone please help!

Comment: Could you please share your source files - `settings.json` and`program.cs` files.

Answer (score 0):

> Settings must be of the form "name=value". at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.CloudStorageAccount when running Azure webjob timer trigger

You haven't added the Storage Account Connection String in `appsettings.json` file.

- Create a Storage Account and copy the Connection String from Access Keys = >`Connection string`.

[image]

Add a new file `appsettings.json` and add the below line

```cs
AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=StorageAccName;AccountKey=****==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
```

Thanks @[christiandersen](https://christiandersen.dk/add-a-timer-triggered-webjob-for-net-5-0/) and [Coding Canvas](https://codingcanvas.com/using-timer-triggers-with-azure-web-jobs/) for the explanation.

For the Web Job to run the timer-trigger we need to set it as a `Scheduled Jobs`.

- Your `settings.json` must contain the below settings.

```cs
{
    "schedule":"0 */15 * * * *",
    "is_singleton":true
}
```

This setting is to specify the CRON expression/ time span which specifies the web job to trigger.